# No Suitable Driver error after setting CLASSPATH, Maven, and pom.xml

Tags: java, azure, maven, jdbc

Since yesterday I have been trying to figure out how to fix this SQLException, and at this point I'm empty. I have checked dozens of sites, the whole documentation for Microsoft and Azure on how to connect with databases, and I keep getting the same error.

I've added a CLASSPATH like `CLASSPATH =.;C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 8.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_8.2\enu\mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre11.jar` as informed on [Using the JDBC Driver documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15). I've downloaded the JDBC driver from Microsoft themselves and dumped the files on a folder in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC DRIVER 8.4 for SQL Server` as their documentation suggests. My `maven` and `java` are working fine, and I have an example class that I've got from `SQLExamples` by Microsoft themselves, this one:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

// As informed on: 
// https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/java/windows/step/2.html

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver:[AzureAddressHere];" 
        + "database=[DatabaseHere];" 
        + "user=[UserHere];"
        + "password=[PasswordHere]";

        try {
            // Load SQL Server JDBC driver and establish connection.
            System.out.print("Connecting to SQL Server ... ");
            try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)) {
                System.out.println("Done.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I've also added the references to the `jar` file to the `pom.xml` dependencies list:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.1.jre11</version>
</dependency>
```

I've also found a mention in a website that the `jar` file sits in Maven's library folder, so I've copied the `jar` file to the `lib` folder as well.

Yet, whenever I try to run the app, I get the `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for [AzureInformation]`.

Any ideas on what I could be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the issue was the lack of two `//` in the address. *facepalm*

So, I just set this line to: `String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://[AzureAddressHere];"` and it finally connected.

To be fair to myself here, this error is so completely unclear and unhelpful.